# There are no values on dataSnapshot.getChildren() when I use startAt()

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I want to use `startAt()` and `limitToFirst()` to create a 'Load More' feature.

```
placeQuery = placesDBRef.limitToFirst(perPage + 1).startAt(placeDataLastIndex); 
placeQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener2);
```

placeDataLastIndexs can be 0, 1, 2, 3, ...

When I receive data in `onDataChange()`, the value of dataSnapshot.getChildren() is null

When I remove `startAt()`, there are values on `dataSnapshot.getChildren()`

Comment: Please make sure the question contains the [minimal code and JSON that are needed to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Start from scratch and reproduce the problem with minimal code and data, hard-coding values where possible. You can get the JSON (as text) by clicking the Export JSON link in the overflow menu in your Firebase Database Console.

Answer (score 0):

If so i'am sure that the mistake is with the value of placeDataLastIndex...Check it throughly wether the value of placeDataLastIndex is within limits...

Comment: I changed **placeDataLastIndex = 3;** It still doesn't work

Comment: try changing it to 0 or remove limitToFirst and check whether then it returns value.